# Расстановка знаков препинания в предложении "Собирайте клубнику и что найдете тоже"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

Не могу разобраться со знаками препинания в следующем предложении:

> Собирайте клубнику и что ещё найдете тоже.

В справочнике Розенталя я нашла, что "и тоже" - это присоединительный член предложения, поэтому должен обособляться запятыми. Допустим, я поставлю запятую перед союзом "и", но нужна ли запятая после "найдете"? Ведь подразумевается "все, что найдете", то есть это придаточная часть. Но в то же время, если ее убрать, останется только "и тоже"("Собирайте клубнику и тоже"), что не имеет смысла.

Понимаю, что предложение выстроено не совсем верно и не следовало бы опускать "все", но так написала одна знакомая в переписке со мной.  Мне стало интересно, как, не меняя структуры, корректно расставить знаки препинания.

Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Обсуждение продолжилось здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467189

Answer (score 1):

Так какая же здесь конструкция, соединительная или присоединительная? От этого зависит постановка запятой перед И.
Пожалуй, остановимся на присоединительной конструкции: Собирайте клубнику, и что ещё найдете тоже. Кстати, пауза в таком предложении весьма желательна (интонационное решение), но надо обосновать выбор с точки зрения грамматики и орфографических правил.

Пояснение

Правило (1) Между придаточным и второстепенным членом возможны ОДНОРОДНЫЕ отношения, тогда запятая перед одиночным союзом И не ставится: Собирайте клубнику и что ещё найдете тоже.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134 Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении, § 115(г)

Правило (2) Но союз И может быть не только соединительным, но и присоединительным, тогда запятая ставится: Собирайте клубнику, и что ещё найдете тоже. Присоединительный характер придает предложению наречие ТОЖЕ. Сравнить: Собирайте клубнику и что ещё найдете. Здесь И – соединительный союз, нет запятой.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120 § 24. Присоединительные конструкции, пункт 1.

Правило (3) Какое здесь союзное средство?  Этот вопрос грамматический, решать его надо точно. Нет сочинительного соединительного союза И ТОЖЕ, хотя есть соединительный союз А ТАКЖЕ, не надо их путать. Слово  ТОЖЕ здесь является наречием, а сочетание И ТОЖЕ – не грамматический союз, а  союзный аналог, который условно может называться присоединительным союзом.

Примечание. Союзы ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ используются для соединения предложений, но не однородных членов, например: Все читали новый роман, я тоже решил его прочесть. Для однородных членов используется только союз А ТАКЖЕ (перед ним ставится запятая).
[http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B)

Правило (4) «Что ещё найдете» – придаточное предложение, а не устойчивый оборот, так как предложение содержит распространитель «еще». (На это абсолютно правильно указывает oleedd). Но на знаках препинания это никак не сказывается.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146 § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения, п. 6

ВЫВОД. Здесь присоединительная конструкция. На знаки препинания оказывает влияние слово ТОЖЕ в составе союзного сочетания И ТОЖЕ, которое можно считать присоединительным союзом. Итак, правильный ответ: Собирайте клубнику, и что ещё найдете тоже. Запятая ставится перед присоединительным союзом И (или И ТОЖЕ).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 14.08.2021 (ответ на комментарий oleedd)

Помните у Тургенева:  «Однако мы довольно философствовали. Природа навевает молчание сна, сказал Пушкин». – «Никогда он ничего подобного не сказал». — «Ну, не сказал, так мог и должен был сказать, в качестве поэта». Вы здесь говорите как Аркадий, а я думаю так – Розенталь не написал, так мог и должен был написать. Эта конструкция встречается ВЕЗДЕ И ВСЮДУ, а ссылок на правило у Розенталя нет, так что приходится их везде разыскивать и к Лопатину обращаться.

Вот у Базарова правильное мышление, он мой герой, а вы не хотите мыслить СВОБОДНО, везде у вас рамки ограничительные. Казалось бы,  ясно видно, что оборот присоединительный (и автор вопроса это чувствует), а для объяснения мы какие-то виртуальные конструкции придумываем (разнообразные, но  весьма сомнительные).  А зачем этим заниматься – надо не стандартное переделывать, а новое строить, ну и правило подходящее  или грамматику какую для убедительности подыскать.

Это не однородные члены, запятая у меня перед И? А что, совсем не однородные? В грамматике сказано, что присоединительные отношения – это ОСОБЫЙ ВИД однородных отношений. Цитата: «Члены ряда могут быть полностью равноправными, а могут быть синтаксически дифференцированными...  Особым типом отношений между членами ряда являются ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ: второй  (или последний) член ряда имеет добавочный характер» (Кустова, стр. 109).

Правила ПАС и  учебная грамматика – разве этого мало? Разве нельзя распространить правило для обычных однородных отношений на отношения присоединительные?

Существует такое понятие, как ОДНОИМЕННЫЕ члены –  синтаксически однородные, но семантически разные (это как раз наш случай).  Также не стоит забывать о синтаксической СИНОНИМИИ (одно содержание может иметь разные грамматические формы). Из этого следует, что не надо привязывать свое сознание к одной единственной, не так ли? Кстати, хорошее жизненное правило…

А вы пытаетесь определить эту единственную форму, а потом перестраиваете ее, чтобы найти доказательство для присоединительной запятой. Вот и выглядят такие рассуждения сложно и не очень убедительно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128552/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Comment: @Sharon полностью присоединяюсь к вашему ответу. Добавить и нечего. Остальные ответы даже дочитать  не смог.

Answer (score 0):

"Тоже" указывает на пропуск повторяющегося глагола (*тоже собирайте*), поэтому перед И ставится запятая. Но:
*Собирайте клубнику и [то,] что ещё найдете.* || Запятая не ставится. Вторым однородным элементом выступает придаточное.
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=384 (пункт г)

В исходном предложении необходимо много запятых по следующей логике:
*Собирайте клубнику, и, что ещё найдете, тоже [собирайте].*
*Собирайте клубнику, и [собирайте] тоже [то], что ещё найдете.*

Логичнее было сказать просто: *собирайте всё, что найдёте*.

> Но в то же время, если ее убрать, останется только "и тоже"("Собирайте клубнику и тоже"), что не имеет смысла.

Это не критерий для пунктуации в случае придаточного. Часто бывает, что больше информации (слов) — в придаточном, а не в главном предложении, поэтому при изъятии придаточного смысла остаётся мало. **Критерий — структура** (стыковка элементов грамматически). К тому же об этом сказано у Розенталя:
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140 (пункт 3)

Update:
Лучше следующее оформление, так как, скорее всего, вторая мысль появилась где-то через секунду, а не сразу:
*Собирайте клубнику. И что ещё найдете, тоже.* || Лишь одна запятая.
Скорее всего, сначала было чёткое указание собирать клубнику, а потом неожиданно пришла мысль — ведь может найтись что-то ещё, так пусть собирают всё.

Comment: В отличие от предложенного варианта, в оригинале нет "всего" (собирайте... что найдёте). Выражение препарирует Розенталево "неразложимое сочетание", которому запятая противопоказана http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146 "Что найдёте" выступает прямым дополнением (не придаточным предложением) и заменяется на "малину" и т. п.

Comment: В случае цельных выражений важен и порядок слов, и отсутствие дополнительных слов, и даже форма глагола: *бери что найдёшь*. Но: *что найдёшь, бери; бери, что ещё найдёшь; брать, что найдёшь*. Если в середине вставлен фрагмент, то ни о какой цельности (неделимости) и речи быть не может — в моём первом примере придаточное. Подкорректировал этот момент в первом абзаце.

Comment: В вашем варианте без "ещё" — вы заметили, что оно присутствует в оригинале, о котором вы говорите? — "*Собирайте клубнику и что найдете*" оно может претендовать на цельность (не придаточное), но в такой конструкции нет логики, так как клубника входит в "что найдёте".

Answer (score 0):

Marie Mit, в этом предложении не нужны никакие знаки препинания кроме точки на конце. Вполне нормальная разговорная конструкция.

> Поправьте, пожалуйста, пунктуацию в своём ответе.

grizzly, с какой стати я должен поправлять то, что правильно?

> И ещё: Вы действительно считаете, что точки ставят "на конце" предложения?

Считаю. А вы, grizzly, ставите точки в других местах? Посередине предложения, например? Интересно...

И ещё: вы действительно считаете, что в середине предложения (не после точки!) местоимения пишутся с прописной буквы? Или это просто описка по невнимательности? Надо быть внимательнее, если уж вы решили раздавать замечания))

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, пунктуацию в своём ответе. И ещё: Вы действительно считаете, что точки ставят "на конце" предложения? Или это просто описка по невнимательности?

Comment: @ЕгорСальков http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/51-rubric-88

Comment: oleedd, ссылка на грамотару человека не украшает) Не надо мне портить моё хорошее мнение о вас!

Comment: Егор, зря Вы так раскипятились: и _Grizzly_ прав, и _oleedd_ прав. Правильное оформление: _...в этом предложении не нужны никакие знаки препинания, кроме точки в конце._ Статистика: точка в конце предложения — 41400, точка на конце предложения — 659. P. S. Все разногласия или претензии, не касающиеся собственно ответа на вопрос, обсуждаются в **комментариях**. Автору интересен ответ, а не копьеметания между участниками.

Comment: "ссылка на грамотару человека не украшает" — ну и сказанули. Разве это плохой сайт? Просто хотелось подметить, что "в середине предложения (не после точки!) местоимения пишутся с прописной буквы" — иногда, то есть ошибки не было.

Comment: А в плане пунктуации — не хватает запятой перед "кроме" (скорее всего, это предлагалось поправить). И ещё: на этом сайте принято не просто отвечать, нужно или нет, а ещё и приводить аргументы. Это важно. Иначе вам никто не поверит.

Comment: "Статистика: точка в конце предложения — 41400, точка на конце предложения — 659". — И что? Мнение 660 (со мной) человек ничего не стоит? А вы уверены, что такие вопросы решаются голосованием? "Разве это плохой сайт?" — Да: для тех, кто хочет писать по-настоящему грамотно, "грамота.ру" — плохой сайт. Вы, видимо, не в курсе, но на вопросы там отвечают на общественных началах студенты младших курсов. И я не считаю, что запятая перед "кроме" в данном случае нужна. Причём никаких аргументов, почему она здесь нужна, я у вас не вижу и, по вашим же словам, я вправе вам не верить))

Comment: *Как правило, оборот с предлогом «кроме» выделяется, если предлог можно заменить словами «исключая, не считая чего-либо».* Это "наш" вариант. https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/359/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5

Comment: "...оборот с предлогом «кроме» выделяется, если предлог можно заменить словами «исключая, не считая чего-либо». Это "наш" вариант". — Нет. Предлог "кроме" здесь должно заменять словами “дополнительно, вдобавок” (к конечной точке).

Comment: "но на вопросы там отвечают на общественных началах студенты младших курсов" — с чего вы взяли? Слухи? Очень интересно. "не нужны никакие знаки препинания, кроме точки на конце" => не нужны, не считая [исключая] точку, которая нужна. Если имеется отрицание, то и речи о "вдобавок" быть не может.

Comment: «"но на вопросы там отвечают на общественных началах студенты младших курсов" — с чего вы взяли?» — А вы с чего взяли, что студенты младших курсов там не отвечают? «Если имеется отрицание, то и речи о "вдобавок" быть не может». — Вы вправе иметь своё мнение.

Comment: На таких основаниях можно утверждать, что там отвечает НЛО. Ладно, может (но это редкость), но точно не в вашем случае: *Кроме молока он не купил ещё сметану.*

Comment: «На таких основаниях можно утверждать, что там отвечает НЛО».  — На каких «таких» основаниях? Не на подобных ли тем, на которых своё мнение основываете вы? «Ладно, может (но это редкость), но точно не в вашем случае: Кроме молока он не купил ещё сметану». — Уважаемый oleedd, где вы увидели «редкость»? У вас элементарный оборот с «кроме» в значении включения. Согласно Лопатину, теперь такие обороты нужно выделять независимо от их значения (видимо, потому, что на практике не всегда легко установить значение). Но по Розенталю оборот «кроме» со значением включения мог обособляться факультативно.

Comment: Собственно, не ставя ту запятую, я ориентировался не на значение включения/выключения, а вот на этот текст в Академике, тем более, что его слово в слово перепечатала и любимая здесь Грамота.ру: «Запятые могут не ставиться, если предлог "кроме" имеет значение "дополнительно, вдобавок к чему-либо".
Кроме школ наши поляки могли бы всё вести там по-своему, да не ведут. Н. Лесков, Город Краков». https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/359/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5

Comment: Продолжение статьи в Академике/Грамоте: «Однако и при таком значении предлога постановка запятых возможна....» Видимо, придётся их здесь ставить, если в противном случае мне светят подобные разборки)) Но всё же: «В этом предложении не нужны никакие знаки препинания дополнительно/вдобавок к точке на конце», т. е. точка нужна, а дополнительно к ней ничего не нужно, — что не так?

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума, можно реплику из зала?  Если посмотреть примеры из Нацкорпуса, то можно убедиться, что обороты с предлогами КРОМЕ и  ВМЕСТО обособляются не по правилам (Розенталя или ПАС), а по структуре и интонации конкретного предложения. Здесь практическая орфография обгоняет теорию, и это вполне закономерное явление (об этом еще Валгина в 2005 году говорила). Новое  оформление сначала закрепляется на практике, а потом уже отражается в правилах.  Эти обороты фактически приравнены к обстоятельственным оборотам, где обособление факультативно.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Ваш аргумент "а с чего вы взяли, что так не происходит?" — это предел маразма, так всё что угодно можно утверждать. Вы отсутствием запятой включаете точку в список того, что "не нужно". Именно такая грамматика. "т. е. точка нужна" — заметьте, что у вас в предложении наоборот — "не нужны" (с "не"). У вас не указано, что точка **нужна**, есть лишь "не нужны". А редкость — в отрицательном глаголе (с "кроме"), так редко говорят.

Comment: «Ваш аргумент "а с чего вы взяли, что так не происходит?" — это предел маразма». — Не думаю. Его пределом здесь был аргумент про НЛО :) Остальные ваши блуждания в трёх соснах оставляю без ответа.

Comment: Вот и хотелось показать предел маразма вашего аргумента :) Проблема вот в чём: лишь одно значение может быть верным — "исключая" или "вдобавок". "Исключая точку" бесспорно подходит. Просто при значении "вдобавок" наблюдается добавление чего-то к чему-то, и в итоге получается наличие как минимум двух элементов.

Comment: Уважаемый oleedd, при всём моём уважении к вам как к представителю Homo sapiens, приходится заметить: маразматические аргументы в моём с вами диалоге явно налицо, но это не мои аргументы :) Разрешите также сообщить, что, с моей точки зрения, всерьёз убеждать собеседника, разговаривающему с тобой на том уровне, на котором со мной разговариваете вы, есть неуважение к себе. А я предпочитаю оставаться уважающим себя человеком. Если вы основательно измените свой стиль в лучшую сторону, я поделюсь с вами своими доводами. Но я сомневаюсь, что это в ваших силах.

Comment: "А вы с чего взяли, что студенты младших курсов там не отвечают?" — убедительный аргумент? В нём нет маразма? А с чего вы взяли, что там не отвечают кандидаты наук? А с чего вы взяли, что там не отвечают преподаватели университета? Зачем клеветать на сайт?

Comment: oleedd, уймитесь. Я уже сообщил вам, на каком условии я согласен продолжать дискуссию. (И теперь ещё больше убеждён, что оно вам не по силам.)

Answer (score 0):

Второй (краткий) ответ

**Собирайте клубнику, и что еще найдете тоже.**

В предложении делается пауза, запятой обособляется присоединительный оборот (присоединительный союз И ТОЖЕ).

Присоединительный характер определяет **слово ТОЖЕ**. Сравнить: *Собирайте клубнику и что еще найдете* (запятую можно не ставить). Но это факультативное решение: в этом предложении союз И может быть как соединительным, так и присоединительным.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ РЕШЕНИЯ

Предложение выглядит нестандартно, поэтому требуется объяснение. Возьмем простое предложение, осложненное присоединительным оборотом: *Собирайте клубнику, и другие ягоды тоже*. В позицию второстепенного члена подставляем придаточное предложение: *Собирайте клубнику, и что еще найдете тоже*.

Comment: Нет общего глагола — нет и однородного элемента. Здесь части самостоятельны (как и в "*Собирайте клубнику, и, что ещё найдете, тоже собирайте.*"), а однородность лишь иллюзия.

Comment: Самостоятельность?  А ее по-разному можно выразить.  Одно и то же содержание имеет несколько грамматических форм, можно выбрать. В заданном предложении эта самостоятельность выражена присоединительным, а не соединительным  оборотом. В разговорной речи используется упрощенный синтаксис, но в то же время очень выразительный. А вы для него ищете книжные образцы.

Comment: А вы попробуйте придумать предложение со словом "тоже" при втором однородном элементе без присоединения.

Comment: А вы когда-нибудь видели  союз ТОЖЕ  (не наречие или частицу) в начале предложения или перед однородным членом? Там только союз А ТАКЖЕ может находиться.  Пример: Все читали новый роман, я тоже решил прочесть. Здесь ТОЖЕ - официальный грамматический союз (не аналог), а стоит в середине предложения (значение соединительно-отождествительное).

Comment: Это бы могло оправдать вашу позицию. "вы когда-нибудь видели союз ТОЖЕ... в начале предложения или перед однородным членом" — а вы его ставите при присоединении "однородного элемента". *Сегодня он собрал сливы, а завтра он собрал груши.* Здесь тоже "груши" и "сливы" выглядят однородными. Так и в вашем случае они лишь выглядят так.

Comment: А вообще, меня заинтересовал ваш подход продолжать основную часть после придаточного как однородного элемента. Тогда и так можно: *Он хотел мороженного и чтобы застолье продолжалось до вечера очень сильно.* "Очень сильно" продолжает основное предложение, как и "тоже" в вашем случае. А Лопатин не просчитывал все варианты, как Розенталь.

Comment: oleedd, я уже не знаю и во всем с вами согласна. А вы случайно не математик, нет?   А то мне стало уже так казаться...

Comment: Нет, но математика нравится. А так что делать? *Он хотел чтобы застолье продолжалось до вечера и мороженного очень сильно.* Розенталь против придаточного как однородного элемента, в справочнике по пунктуации решил это не рассматривать. У Лопатина лишь базовый случай.

Comment: Получено предупреждение от системы, не будем испытывать терпение модераторов. Предложение у вас неправильное, совершенно "математическое".  Его нельзя использовать.

Comment: Да всё нормально, это уже другой ответ, а те комментарии ушли в чат. Это всё автоматические действия, с терпением они не связаны. Можно упростить, так уже получше: *Он хотел чтобы гости не уходили и поесть мороженного.*

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий для @Sharon с анализом предложенной структуры

У вас должно быть так, чтоб было правильно:
*Собирайте клубнику, и также [кроме того] что ещё найдете.* || Нет пропуска глагола. Пауза краткая. Придаточное относится напрямую к "собирайте". "Также" хорошо применяется при однородных элементах.
"Также" можно переставить в конец:
*Собирайте клубнику, и что ещё найдете также.* || Логического ударения на придаточном (на "ещё") быть не должно. Не лучший порядок.

Пробуем "тоже" переставить в начало:
*Собирайте клубнику, и тоже что ещё найдете.* || Не сильно оно подходит при однородном элементе. Так меняется ситуация: либо оно примыкает к однородному элементу (здесь), либо подразумевает пропущенный глагол.

Но смысл в конструкции выше другой:
*Собирайте клубнику, и ещё остальное.*
А в оригинале следующий:
Собирайте клубнику, а с остальным поступайте таким же образом. Там мыслится второй глагол, а пауза длиннее.

Comment: oleedd, я хочу задать новый вопрос по данной теме, чтобы более четко обозначить проблему.

Comment: А вы ощущаете вложенный смысл? Для этого прочитайте фрагменты так, будто они отдельные предложения. Сначала было указание собирать клубнику, а потом неожиданно пришла мысль — ведь может найтись что-то ещё, так пусть собирают всё. Присоединения тут мало, тут не то что как ССП, а как отдельные предложения можно оформить: *Собирайте клубнику. И что ещё найдете, тоже.*

Comment: СПАСИБО  вам за внимание к теме! Самое близкое  по содержанию предложение (синтаксический синоним) такое: Собирайте клубнику, а также что ещё найдете.  Я полагаю, что это  простое предложение, осложненное присоединительным оборотом. В позиции  сочетания "другие ягоды" находится придаточное.  Здесь все корректно: присоединительный союз А ТАКЖЕ (синоним И+ТОЖЕ), запятая ставится.

Comment: Вот такая структура лучшим образом отражает вашу позицию. А я считаю, что вторая мысль появилась через время и оптимальное содержание такое: *Собирайте клубнику! А что ещё найдёте, собирайте тоже.* => *А с остальным поступайте так же.*

Comment: Есть разница в интонации: в вашей она идёт вниз (особенно слово "тоже"), а в моей — вверх.

Comment: У нас одно предложение, а не два.  Автор просил ничего не менять (напоминаю вам еще раз).

Comment: А вы поменяли в комментарии выше, а я следом.

Comment: Ничего я не меняла, это синтаксический синоним, а не вариант. Я вам просто доказывала сходство двух вариантов. Всё, конец связи, система ругается!  Лучше на мой вопрос  дайте качественный ответ, тогда я конкурс устрою (будет хотя бы два ответа). Александр со мной не соглашался, но у него доказанное мнение. Он тоже мой оппонент, и поэтому я положительно оцениваю его ответ.   Мне не согласие нужно, а  четкая позиция тех, кто со мной не согласен.

Comment: Совет: задавайте непосредственно вопросы, если хотите получить ответы.

Comment: *Лучше на мой вопрос дайте качественный ответ, тогда я конкурс устрою  (будет хотя бы два ответа)* — конкурсы нужны как раз для того, чтоб было больше ответов, чаще всего — чтоб они вообще появились. *С одним конкурсом у меня не получается* — чего это?