# Сколько правильных предложений можно подобрать для одного содержания?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, грамматика

1. Это **принципиальный подход** к решению задач по синтаксису и пунктуации, поэтому я уделяю этому вопросу так много времени.

Содержание всегда можно представить в **описательном** виде, но потом мы должны подобрать для него правильную грамматическую форму.  **Сколько их?** Думается, что несколько, поэтому нельзя  говорит о грамматической правильности только одной.  Искать **единственно верный вариант** – тупиковый способ, надо учитывать синтаксическую **синонимию**.

Правильных вариантов может быть несколько, и каждая правильно построенная грамматическая форма **самодостаточна и верна**.  Давайте относиться к ней с уважением, а именно: ничего не добавлять и ничего не переставлять, ничего не додумывать и не перестраивать.  Иначе это будет уже другое предложение.

Для каждой конкретной ситуации есть несколько форм, но одна из них **наиболее оптимальна**, то есть подходит наилучшим образом (по содержанию и стилю текста).

Такие вопросы возникают при оценке нестандартных предложений, когда мы пытаемся привести их к какому-то стандарту . Причем привести, перекраивая известные нам конструкции. Я думаю, что это неправильно.

Эта проблема так и не решена в вопросе  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466984/Расстановка-знаков-препинания-в-предложении-Собирайте-клубнику-и-что-найдете-то](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466984/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE).

Помогите, пожалуйста, а я постараюсь не остаться в долгу.

2. Вот два конкретных предложения. Меня интересует правильность грамматики и пунктуации и  независимый синтаксический разбор каждого предложения (простое или сложное, вид осложнения).  Какой из вариантов наиболее оптимален для заданного содержания. Есть ли другие варианты?
   Можно очень коротко, просто ваш вариант разбора с небольшим обоснованием.

(1) Собирайте клубнику, и другие ягоды тоже.

(2) Собирайте клубнику, и что еще найдете тоже.

**Содержание предложений** (описательные варианты):

Собирайте клубнику, ну и все остальное, что попадется. Или: Собирайте клубнику, а если еще что-то найдете, то собирайте тоже. И т.д.
Мысль ясная, причем очевидно, что содержание делится на две части (сообщение о двух ситуациях, основной и дополнительной). Стиль **разговорный**, не книжный (это надо учитывать).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**
Возможно, это будет конкурсный вопрос, если будут ответы.

Что мне хотелось бы услышать. В задаче даны примеры предложений, для которых нужно сделать синтаксический разбор. Но главное для меня – это **вопрос о нестандартном синтаксисе предложения** (2). Там в позиции однородного члена находится придаточное, а также задан  присоединительный характер сообщения. Есть **два разных подхода** к решению таких задач.

(1)  Синтаксис нестандартного предложения определяется по грамматическим учебникам.  У такого предложения **самостоятельная грамматика,**  для него не надо искать стандартный образец в правилах Розенталя и ПАС. Синтаксический разбор делается именно для этого предложения.

(2) Синтаксис нестандартного предложения приводится **к стандарту по справочнику письма**: что-то вырезается, что-то приклеивается. Что берется за стандарт? А что кому нравится, поэтому возможны варианты. Мне такой подход кажется некорректным и устаревшим, хотя им пользуются многие.

Comment: "поэтому я уделяю **эту** вопросу"...

Comment: oleedd, а как насчет того, чтобы самому исправить "эту вопросу".  Сделали бы мне одолжение. И вообще, это орфографический редактор так написал, я не могу по две буквы пропускать.

Answer (score 1):

С пунктом 1 из вопроса я согласен (без учёта спорного словосочетания "наиболее оптимальный"): в рассуждениях о пунктуации не стоит видоизменять грамматическую
конструкцию до степени появления *придаточного* предложения в исходном простом или сложносочинённом.

Пункт 2. В двух имеющихся примерах я бы не поставил запятую на одном только интонационном основании (интонация к этому не обязывает, хотя пауза возможна - присоединяемая часть могла быть сказана вдогонку; для обозначения случившейся в речи паузы я бы поставил многоточие). Без добавленного "тоже" можно рассматривать не только первое, но и второе предложение как простое *с однородными членами* (собирайте А и Б), если трактовать "что ещё найдёте" как неразложимое сочетание в функции прямого дополнения. Что же добавляет к этому находящееся в конце предложения "тоже"? Отсылку к имеющемуся в предложении единственному сказуемому, и только. Но даже если повторить его после "тоже" (такой приём ранее предлагался), запятая не появится, хотя предложение из простого перейдёт в разряд сложносочинёных (что методологически неудачно), с двумя одинаковыми императивами при общем адресате. Соответственно, запятая в этих предложениях для меня выглядит *лишней*.

Comment: Многоточие не подходит, потому что первая часть — это чёткое указание, без раздумий. А затем появилась мысль, что и что-то другое можно найти.

Comment: Alex_ander, мне кажется, на интонационном основании можно было бы (не утверждаю, что нужно) поставить тире. Кстати, именно для правильной интонации так мучающее некоторых «тоже» в конце этих предложений совершенно необходимо. Не синтаксисом единым жив язык: «тоже» позволяет повысить тон к концу, и это делает фразу по-настоящему «приглашающей». И да: я горячо присоединяюсь к лишности запятой в обоих предложениях: запятая — знак препинания, а не интонации.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, правильных (грамматически?) предложений, доносящих одну и ту же определённую мысль, всегда можно составить очень и очень много. А что из них подобрать — зависит от установки подбирающего :)

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.   Пока есть два варианта, так что их надо сравнить: какая грамматика, правильная ли грамматика, какой вариант более удачный. Второе предложение содержит больше информации. Возможно, есть и другие варианты, но не думаю, что их очень много.  Скорее всего,  варианты можно оценивать  достаточно объективно, а не только по своему вкусу. В то же время у каждого автора свой стиль письма, а у каждого говорящего свои особенности речи. Некоторые писать не умеют, но так говорят, что заслушаешься. Это, кстати, запись устной речи, а там ценится краткость и выразительность.

Comment: Возможно, вопрос будет конкурсный (как дело пойдет, конкурс по правилам можно объявить через два дня). Может, что нибудь добавите к ответу?

Comment: Сейчас или на конкурсе? И что именно мне добавить?

Comment: Sharon, я уже вам ответил в предыдущем вопросе. Но повторюсь. Добавить мне нечего. Полностью поддерживаю ваш ответ.

Comment: «какой вариант более удачный». — Удачный с точки зрения кого? «Возможно, есть и другие варианты, но не думаю, что их очень много». — На самом деле их — всегда — очень много. «Скорее всего, варианты можно оценивать достаточно объективно, а не только по своему вкусу». — Скорее всего, нет: скачут даже цены на вполне материальное золото, тем более оценка такой нематериальной вещи, как «фраза», возможна только личная и ни для кого не обязательная.

Comment: Это вопрос стилистики, даже на форуме мы часто помогаем  выбрать более подходящий вариант.  Для художественного произведения важна образность, для разговорного - краткость и выразительность, для информационных сообщений - оптимальное соотношение полезной информации и объема.   Да вот недавно был вопрос по стилевой правке, да только никто и не подумал ответить. Но там просили не трогать структуру, а в других случаях это можно и нужно делать. Да все редактирование сводится к поиску оптимального варианта.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Я добавила информацию про конкурсный вопрос, мне было бы интересно ваше мнение.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий к ответу Alex_ander**

Большое спасибо вам за ответ. Комментарий будет такой.

1. **Слово ТОЖЕ однозначно задает присоединительный характер  второго сообщения.**

В ССП это **грамматический союз**, например: Я ничего не понял, он тоже. Союз ТОЖЕ  относится к основным средствам связи (входит в список основных союзов), значение оотождествительно-соединительное. Союз находится в середине или в конце предложения, в начало  его никто не ставит.

В остальных случаях ТОЖЕ – это **наречие** со значением «равным образом, в равной мере».  Для однородных членов используется сочетание  **И + ТОЖЕ**, и это уже **союзный аналог**, он состоит из присоединительного союза И и наречия ТОЖЕ, значение у этого аналога **присоединительное**.  Кстати, в начале предложения ТОЖЕ  и в данном случае  не встречается.

Я полагаю, что И не может быть соединительным союзом при наличии ТОЖЕ, так как связь здесь **неоднородная**.  Мы всегда будем  иметь основное сообщение и дополнительное. Поэтому присутствие ТОЖЕ однозначно говорит о том, что связь **присоединительная, а запятая ставится**.  А вот одиночный союз И может быть и соединительным, и присоединительным.

По поводу **отсылки ТОЖЕ к глаголу**. Не надо его туда отсылать, он относится ко всему предложению и является детерминантом.

Примечание. В моем задаче **присоединительный характер** второй части предложения указан уже в содержании.

**2. Нужно ли переводить придаточное предложение в устойчивый оборот?**

Конечно, хочется перевести, тогда предложение будет однозначно простым, а проблем  будет меньше. Здесь мешает слово-распространитель ЕЩЁ, надо бы его **убрать.**

И тогда получается, что **и содержание, и грамматика второстепенны** по отношению к правилам письма? Автор не имеет возможности использовать нужные ему слова, а **грамматику мы изучаем по справочнику Розенталя?**  Если есть там пример с определенной грамматикой, то ее можно использовать, а в противном случае нельзя?  Странная ситуация, не правда ли? Грамматические конструкции лучше изучать по соответствующим учебникам, а нерешенные задачи решать самим по аналогии с решенными образцами.